# Compare spans in a list and return a label if similar

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, nlp, python-itertools

I want to build a list of labels to match the words in a sentence

```
sentence="I am a healthy boy who lives in Florida"
subject= "I am a healthy boy"
```

first I split:

```
sen = sentence.split(" ")
subj = subject.split(" ")
```

then I try to iterate.

```
tokens=[]
tokensStartIndex = 0
for i in range(0,len(sen)):
 ...
```

I want to have this as a result:

```
sentence = "I am a healthy boy who lives in Florida"
labels   = [sub sub sub sub sub 0 0 0 0]
```

and how do I iterate this over a dataframe of columns sentence and subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done quite easily using regular expressions.

```
sentence="I am a healthy boy who lives in Florida"
subject= "I am a healthy boy"
```

## Build the expression

```
abc = '({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(y) for y in sorted(subject, key=len, reverse=True)))
```

## Iterate the expression over the sentence

```
xyz = (re.sub(abc, r"sub" , sent) for sent in sentence)
```

## Build new list and filter

```
new = [new_sentence for old_sentence, new_sentence in zip(sentence, xyz) if old_sentence != new_sentence]
```

new

voila!